# Can I use a coloured square as a link instead of text using CSS?

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
.style-switcher {overflow: auto;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.style-switcher > li {float: left;list-style-type: none;width: 1em;}
.style-switcher > li > a {display: block;width: 1em;}

<ul class="style-switcher">
   <li><a href="#" data-style="humanity">A</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-style="vader">B</a></li>
</ul>

$(".style-switcher").on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var style = $(this).attr('data-style');
    changeStyle('/Content/Themes-jQuery/' + style + '/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Instead of having the user click on "A" or "B" I would like the user to click on a 
colored square and I would like each colored square to have maybe 2px spacing.

Is there an easy way that I could achieve this so that just colored squares appeared instead of A and B ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this character: ■

It's U+25A0.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use images or you can create a 2x2 div with the desired background color of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I use the below style

```
.buttonlink
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    /*border: 4px outset yellow;*/
}
```

Comment: Can you consider providing a comment for voting down this answer??